# Использование DisplayAttribute в DevExpress WF GridControl

Tags: c#, winforms, gridview, devexpress, display

Возникла следующая проблема:
У меня есть GridControl и GridView. Столбцы в этом представлении генерируются автоматически при установке DataSource для GridControl'а.
Я использую DisplayAttribute для настройки отображения этих столбцов.

Сейчас возникла необходимость поменять столбцы местами.
Как я понял, за это отвечает DisplayAttribute.Order.
Вопрос: Почему, при установке любого значения Order весь атрибут Display перестает работать ?
Есть какой то способ это починить или использовать иной способ?

Мой код простой:

```
private void gridControl_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    BindingList<DocumentWatchList> watchList = new BindingList<DocumentWatchList>();
    this.gridControl.DataSource = watchList;
}

public class DocumentWatchList
{
    [Display(Name = "Информация", Order = 1)]
    public string Info { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Непонятно, не должен переставать работать. А на [этом примере](https://github.com/DevExpress-Examples/how-to-apply-data-annotations-e2579) тоже не работает если поменять код как у вас?

Comment: Посмотрел пример, понял, что у мея перестает все работать именно при отрицательном значении Order.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел решение проблемы самостоятельно. Быть может комму-то будет полезно.
Дело было в том, что поддержка данного атрибута присутствует только в последних версиях DevExpress.
Мой рабочий проект был на версии 13.2, ошибка присутствовала.
При тестировании я случайно использовал 15.2 и все работало.
Удачи!